# How do I create a mutable reference to an object in another object?

Tags: nim-lang

When I try to create two objects, where the second object has a reference to the first, I get `Error: invalid type: 'var Foo' in this context: 'Bar' for var`:

```
type
  Foo = object
    x: int
  
type
  Bar = object
    foo: var Foo

var f = Foo(x: 10)
var b = Bar(foo: f)
```

https://play.nim-lang.org/#ix=3RG3

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to create a `ref Object` for `Foo`. You can see plenty of examples for this in the sources (e.g. JsonNode and JsonNodeObj [here](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/devel/lib/pure/json.nim)), and is documented [here](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-tuples-and-object-types) and [here](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#types-reference-and-pointer-types).

```
type
  Foo = object of RootObj
    x: int
  FooRef = ref Foo

  Bar = object
    foo: FooRef

var f = FooRef(x: 10)
var b = Bar(foo: f)

f.x = 30
doAssert b.foo.x == 30
```

The suffix of the object is not mandatory, but the convention is to use `Ref` for the `ref object`s and `Obj` for value objects ([naming conventions](https://nim-lang.github.io/Nim/nep1.html#introduction-naming-conventions)). E.g. you can write the above as:

```
type
  Foo = ref FooObj
  FooObj = object of RootObj
    x: int

  Bar = object
    foo: Foo

var f = Foo(x: 10)
var b = Bar(foo: f)

f.x = 30
doAssert b.foo.x == 30
```

Answer (score 1):

The var keyword isn't valid in a type declaration context. If there is a need of nested mutable objects, you just need to declare the root one with `var` rather than with `let`, but not in the type declaration.

Here's how to do that:

```
type
  Foo = object
    x: int
  
type
  Bar = object
    foo: Foo

var f = Foo(x: 10)
var b = Bar(foo: f)

b.foo.x = 123

echo b
```

Comment: That isn't a reference to f. If x of the original f is changed, it won't change in b